# convert string of imperial units to a double

Tags: java, string, math, type-conversion

I was wandering  how to pragmatically convert strings  like "5ft 4in" to a its double value in centimeters. What String methods should I use to convert this etc?

Comment: Will the String always be of the format `\d+ft \d+in`?  As in "10ft 5in", "4ft 3in" or it will change to things like "5 feet", "3feet and 1 inch", "3ft 7 inches"

Comment: It will not change. It would always be in the above mentioned format.

Comment: How about doing some research yourself: lookup class `java.lang.String` in the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) and see if there are methods that might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some clues on how to go through this. You need to

1. parse the string to get its numerical values (in your example, get the number of feet, and the number of inches)
2. convert all values to a the same unit in the imperial system (say inches : taking the smaller is easier, so multiply your number of feet by 12)
3. add all your same-unit imperial values together (so 5*12+4) into a single value (in inches)
4. Multiply that number of inches by the number of cm per inch (so multiply your value by 2.54)